# PHP url to array

Tags: php, arrays, url

I have these urls from a **web log**:

```
http://www.domain.com/page?s=194&client=151678&m=a4a&v=1&g=54
http://www.domain.com/page?s=51&client=617171&m=b4z&v=8&g=97
```

How can I convert this URL in an array in PHPso i will have an array like this

```
array(
 'page' => array(
   's' => 194,
   'client' => 151678
   'm' => 'a4a',
   'v' => 1,
   'g' => 54
 )
 etc..
)
```

then later I can loop to that array to find duplicates or validate the information correctly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this but this is what I came up with.

```
<?php

    $url = 'http://www.domain.com/page?s=194&client=151678&m=a4a&v=1&g=54';
    $remove_http = str_replace('http://', '', $url);
    $split_url = explode('?', $remove_http);
    $get_page_name = explode('/', $split_url[0]);
    $page_name = $get_page_name[1];

    $split_parameters = explode('&', $split_url[1]);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($split_parameters); $i++) {
        $final_split = explode('=', $split_parameters[$i]);
        $split_complete[$page_name][$final_split[0]] = $final_split[1];
    }

    var_dump($split_complete);

?>
```

http://codepad.org/xTsAks46

Answer (score 34):

PHP has a native function for that, the [parse_str](http://php.net/parse_str) function. You can use it like:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $outputArray);
```

This will do just what you need.

Comment: This is the preferred method as it supports any standard string that separates by & and =. Works great for curl responses as well

Answer (score 6):

With [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) you can parse the URL to an associative array. In the result array you get amongst others the query part. Then you can use  [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str) for parsing the query part to your new array.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming from your question that path will always be `/page`, the array containing the parsed URLs cannot have multiple `page` indexes so you should use numeric indexes.

Try this:

```
$urls_parsed = array();
foreach ($url_strings as $url_string) {
    $url = parse_url($url_string);
    $urls_parsed[] = parse_str($url['query']);
}
```

`$url_strings` is an array containing all the URLs you want to parse in string format.
`$urls_parsed` is the resulting array containing the URLs parsed in the format you requested.

Answer (score 1):

Use parse_url function like

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';
print_r(parse_url($url));
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>
```

Which will give you the following array output

```
Array
(
[scheme] => http
[host] => hostname
[user] => username
[pass] => password
[path] => /path
[query] => arg=value
[fragment] => anchor
)
```

And from the query you can easily split it as to (key,value) paira. Hope this helps.:)

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
function convertUrlToArray($url){
    $url = str_replace("http://www.domain.com/page?", "", $url);
    $urlExploded =  explode("&", $url);
    $return = array();
    foreach ($urlExploded as $param){
        $explodedPar = explode("=", $param);
         $return[$explodedPar[0]] = $explodedPar[1];
    }
    return $return;

}

$url1 = convertUrlToArray("http://www.domain.com/page?s=51&client=617171&m=b4z&v=8&g=97");
var_dump($url1);
```

example here http://codepad.org/KIDKPzaU